# html2canvas.js not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html2canvas

I keep fiddling with html2canvas and having issues with it, and now it works in every browser except Firefox. The code I have now is:

```
var renderStage=document.getElementById('renderstage');
var doneImage=document.getElementById('doneimage');

html2canvas(renderStage).then(function(canvas) {
var img = canvas.toDataURL();

 $('<img>',{src:img}).appendTo(doneImage);    
});
```

The code is basically using html2canvas on a div, and then appending that resulting img to a new div further down the page. At least, it does in every browser but Firefox.
I checked my console but there are no errors regarding it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with your code?  The examples on https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html all work for me in all versions of Firefox.

Comment: I just checked that the promise version works correctly in Firefox as well.  If you inject the `html2canvas` script into this page then the code snippet: `html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});` works as expected.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I call the html2canvas, and then the snippet to no avail. He's not the only one with this issue.